# Which use of the verb cause is correct in the sentences below?

Tags: verbs

Why does reserpine administration causes a decreases in vascular tone and blood pressure?

Why does reserpine administration cause a decreases in vascular tone and blood pressure?

Comment: It should be "Why does the administration cause decreases in vascular tone and blood pressure?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use 'is' or 'are' with this complex subject?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97648/should-i-use-is-or-are-with-this-complex-subject)

Comment: Note that the use of "cause" seems a bit off, to me at least. Is this what you are trying to say: "Why does the administration reduce vascular tone and blood pressure?"

Comment: The answer to the "embodied" question is [*Reserpine lowers blood pressure **by slowing down your nervous system**.*](https://www.drugs.com/mtm/reserpine.html) But you probably knew that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question.

The correct verb form is **cause**.  However, changing this to a statement we see:

> Reserpine administration causes a decrease in vascular tone and blood pressure.

to which the response may well be your original phrase:

> Why does reserpine administration cause a decrease in vascular tone and blood pressure?

In my statement **causes** is the main verb in the sentence and so is used in the third person singular form.  (You can see more at [this link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/cause)).

In the follow up question it's no longer the main verb (**does** is the main verb) so we use the *plain form* of the verb.

More information on forms of verbs at [this link](https://everything2.com/title/plain+form).

Like I said, good question!

Comment: You need to omit that "a" between "cause" and "decreases".

Comment: @AIQ - thanks for your helpful comment - I have edited the answer.

Comment: I think a "full" answer should explain ***why*** it's correct. Which is that the ***conjugated*** verb form is ***does***, so the "main" verb associated with that "auxiliary" verb should be in the [unmarked] ***infinitive*** form - *[to] **cause***.

Comment: ...my comment coincided with your edit. ***Cause*** here is an infinitive, not "third person singular form".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thanks for your great comments.  I stated that 'causes' is third person singular form (i.e.: conjugated) as that term appears on the link that I provided.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't read the amended text carefully enough, and thought your ***and so is used*** part was explaining why the correct verb form for OP's context is ***cause***, not ***causes***.